# who can tell me how to configure weblogic11g server for soa application more details.. better step by step

Tags: weblogic, soa, jdeveloper

i was fresh to use jdeveloper11g weblogic11g ,want to study SOA ,but  it's stucked. can u help me ..... i will be very grateful to u!
i have download the WS-BPEL 2.0 for SOA Composite Applications with Oracle SOA Suite 11g 's code . When i try to deploy the AmericanAirlines service component , the jdeveloper tells me ![no soa configured servers][1] 
but i totally don't know how to config weblogic server for SOA applications.
please help me .. better step by step , i will be very grateful to u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install an SOA Server - download it from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/index.html

Comment: I have installed jdevstudio11117install.exe ;oepe-wls-indigo-installer-11.1.1.8.0.201110211138-10.3.6-win32;ofm_osb_generic_11.1.1.7.0_disk1_1of1;ofm_rcu_win_11.1.1.7.0_32_disk1_1of1;ofm_soa_generic_11.1.1.7.0_disk1_1of2;ofm_soa_generic_11.1.1.7.0_disk1_2of2;OracleXE112_Win32. But i don't know how to use them  even to make a simple SOA application and deploy it in the standalone weblogic server ...please help me ..

Comment: If you don't know how to install and configure the servers - you might want to start with a pre-existing configured virtual box that you can get here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=tumblr#soa

Answer (score 0):

Before you continue installation please verify the compatible version list.These are the following steps you need to follow.

1. Have Weblogic installed first
2. Install oracle database if you don't have one (An xe database would also suffice)
3. Install rcu by providing the connection details of the database. Remember or make a note of the username and passwords you provide here
4. Install OSB if you are planning to you can skip this step if you don't need
5. Install SOA on the top of weblogic (Caution Jdeveloper also have a weblogic installation make sure you provide the installation folder of weblogic standalone server)
6. Now go ahead and configure domain of weblogic server. It is straight forward gui to do

Thanks...